# Detecting IE10+ loading state

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

When the browser is doing something, it sometimes displays a circle in the tab to show that the page is loading for example.

Is it possible to detect that, and get the mouse cursor to change to show the user that's IE is doing something?

I understand that I can write javascript to simulate such behavior, but I wanted to know if it possible to capture the state of IE more directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

**CSS**

```
body { cursor:progress; }
body.loaded { cursor:default; }
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className+=' loaded';
}
```

For all browsers

Comment: Sorry, Just read the caveat, that you already know you can 'simulate in JS' -  let me know if you want to delete it and leave this 'unanswered'

Comment: if so, by 'more directly', you mean by using what ? CSS ?

Comment: I don't know to be honest.  What I mean is somehow tap into the loading icon of the tab, and check it's state.  If it's state is loading, change the mouse cursor?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not possible to tap into that part of IE using client side scripting?

Comment: Javascript *is* client side scripting , so I'm not sure what you mean exactly. This example is likely your best / shortest bet. ( I don't see another way to look for the page loading event other than javaScript ) - html can't and css can't - what then, activex, applets , browser extensions etc .. ergghh

Comment: I was basically after something like this cursor.state = ie10.tab.state (probably too high a level of scripting which most likely isn't possible yet). So you're most likely right to say that window.onload is probably the best/shortest way.